# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode' 3

Tags: python

I have the python script for reading a excel to xml format but it was showing some error as

```
val = sh.row_values(row)[i].encode("utf-8")
Attribute Error : 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Here is my code:

```
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("my_excel_file.xlsx")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
tags = [n.replace(" ", "").lower() for n in sh.row_values(0)]

result = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<myItems>\n" 

for row in range(1, sh.nrows): 
    result += "  <item>\n"
    for i in range(len(tags)):    
       tag = tags[i].encode("utf-8")
       val = sh.row_values(row)[i].encode("utf-8")   
       result += "    <%s>%s</%s>\n" % (tag, val, tag)    
    result += "  </item>\n"

result += "</myItems>"   

f = open("myfile.xml", "w")
f.write(result)
f.close()
```

Comment: please clarify what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

you've got a float in there where you're needing a string. convert it like this:

```
   val = str(sh.row_values(row)[i]).encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable answer